# List<Type> is missing interop type marshalling data - .NET Native

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, .net-native

I've a project that runs very fine without .NET Native tool chain, but as soon as I activate it, I get an exception about missing interop type marshalling data:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Type] is missing interop type marshalling data. To enable interop type marshalling data, add a MarshalObject directive to the application rd.xml file.

I've tried to add the whole namespace in the *Default.rd.xml* file:

```xml
<Namespace Name="System.Collections.Generic" Dynamic="Required All"/>
```

but it doesn't help.

What should I put there to make the project work with .NET Native?

What is the difference in enabling single type/whole namespace? Is there any impact on performance, memory or something different?

Comment: Could you try adding `MarshalObject="Required All"` to your declaration?

Comment: Might it be missing type information for the specific type of the *type parameter* rather than `List`?

Comment: @KevinGosse Currently I got to work and I will check that once I return home. Will give you a sign.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hmm, that can be an idea, I will also try that way once I return home.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? What's wrong in the question?

Comment: Also, to answer your another question, `Is there any impact on performance, memory or something different?`. The more types you include, the bigger the binary will be. Obviously it impacts memory consumption a tiny bit, but the main difference is startup time

Comment: @KevinGosse I've added declaration like this: `<Type Name="System.Collections.Generic.List" Dynamic="Required All" MarshalObject="Required All"/>` with no luck - the same problem. I've also added the declaration for type and the same situation. I will give it couple more tries tomorrow.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've also added the type like this: `<Type Name="TheType" Dynamic="Required All"  MarshalObject="Required All"/>`, besides the list. The situation haven't changed. I will play with this little more later.

Comment: If you run your scenario in DEBUG but with .NET Native enabled you should get more helpful strings (we're less likely to have stripped type name info and other things). Project Properties > BUILD > Enable .NET Native

Comment: @MattWhilden On normal *Debug* it works flawlessly, on *Release* it just crashed. I've already enabled .NET Native - this is where exception come from. It seems that I've found the solution - I was missing the brackets. Thanks for input.

Comment: @KevinGosse A stupid mistake from my side - I was missing the brackets `{}` - have tried different combinations with `List` and forgot about `List<>`. Thanks for input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried number of different combinations with *Dynamic* and *MarshalObject* to `<Namespace...>` and/or `<Type...>` finally it turned out that I was only missing the brackets `{}`:

```xml
<Type Name="System.Collections.Generic.List{}" MarshalObject="Required All"/>
```

Comment: Happy you're unblocked. We have a little directive builder at https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html that can help a bit. It will cough up correct syntax if nothing else. :-)

Comment: @MattWhilden Yeah, my users will also be happy :). Those damn brackets just took me few hours. I've used the tool you have linked before - it's a nice helping tool.